# Getting plain text from Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on making a blog with [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). I have a text box that stores the `title`, a textarea that stores the `content` of my blog entry, and a "Submit" button. When I press the button I insert a `title` and `content` field into a Meteor Collection called `Entries`.

In my HTML I use this template to render the blog entry:

```
<template name="cur_entries">
  {{#each entries}}
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    {{#markdown}}
{{content}}
    {{/markdown}}
    <hr>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

And the  Javascript for `entries` is:

```
Template.cur_entries.entries = function() {
    return Entries.find({}, {sort: {date_created: -1}});
}
```

It only partly works. Leaving the `title` textbox blank, writing [this markdown example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/10/the-future-of-markdown.html) in my `content` textarea, and pressing "Submit" results in this:

[image]

As you can see the ">" is preserved, and instead of having `"`s, there are `&quot;`s. I believe when text gets posted from the Meteor Collection, it is formatted to be "correctly" rendered by HTML, instead of just plain text. Unfortunately, in this case, I don't want this convenience. Is there any way to get just plain text from a Meteor Collection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using 3 curly brackets to render them as HTML.

```
{{#markdown}}
  {{{content}}}
{{/markdown}}
```

Comment: Oh, was looking in the Meteor documentation and stuff for the answer when I guess I should have been looking at the handlebars docs. XD My bad. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: glad that it worked. Not sure about this, but i think if you are taking content from user inputs you might have to sanitise them.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, the {{#markdown}} right now is still in shark branch.